# Uploading app to itunes from xcode 7.3.1 for iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios10

My current project app settings are xcode 7.3.1,I am using swift 2.2.
My app supports iOS 8 and above. With the recent changes to security and privacy setting for iOS 10, I wanted to know if uploading my app from xcode 7.3.1 will cause any issue/rejection from apple with respect to iOS 10. Is it suggested that I migrate to swift 2.3 and upload the app through xcode 8?Really puzzled

Answer (score 3):

First point: The app store / iTunes Connect doesn't know or care what language your app is written in.

Second point: If you build with Xcode 7.3.1, then you are not linked against iOS 10. Therefore nothing about iOS 10 applies to you. You are running as an iOS 9 (or lower) app, under iOS 9 rules, *even on an iOS 10 device*.

Conclusion: You're fine; nothing has changed merely because Xcode 8 and iOS 10 exist.

Caveat: But you should check by running on an iOS 10 device anyway!

Comment: Yes would agree with you, was just double checking to be sure.Its Apple after all (pun intended)

Comment: Think of it this way. Imagine your app had appeared in the App Store the day before iOS 10 came out. Do you really think it would stop working the next day, just because iOS 10 now also exists?